# I am using Swoole to start a web service and using Sanctum for authentication in Laravel 7

Tags: php, swoole, sanctum

Sanctum Version
2.15.1

Laravel Version
7

PHP Version
7.4

Description
I am using Swoole to start a web service and using Sanctum for authentication in Laravel 7. However, there is an issue: after successfully logging out, the token table in the database is cleared but still shows as logged in status. Only after restarting Swoole and making a new request will it prompt for a token again. How can I clean up excess authentication data to avoid continuously occupying memory and keeping users in a logged-in state?

Logic code for logging out
`Auth::user()->tokens()->delete();`

I hope to initialize this verification instance every time  I use it.

Please help me, thank you.